# Exception occurred processing WSGI script - IOError: failed to write data

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-uploads

I'm trying to save an image at the server side.I recieve it as base64 string so I decode it first and then save it in the database.However this failed, so I checked the server error log and I found the following
error.log

```
    [Tue May 21 14:26:38 2013] [error] [client 41.236.182.133] mod_wsgi (pid=4952): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/root/AR_BROWSER/example/wsgi.py'.
[Tue May 21 14:26:38 2013] [error] [client 41.236.182.133] IOError: failed to write data
```

I checked wsgi.py

```
import os
import sys

path = '/root/AR_BROWSER/example'

sys.path.append('/root/AR_BROWSER/example')
sys.path.append('/root/AR_BROWSER')
sys.path.append('/root/AR_BROWSER/example/app')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

But i can't find something wrong. Any idea what could be the cause of this issue?!
the code responsible for saving the image

```
 @csrf_exempt    
    def create_app(request):
        appName = request.POST['name']
        user = request.POST['userID']
        c = request.POST['category']
        i = request.POST['image']
        imgdata = base64.b64decode(i)
        t = datetime.now()
        filename = t.strftime('test.jpg')  
        with open(filename, 'w') as f:
            f.write(imgdata)
            f.close()
        u=App_User.objects.get(id=user)
        apps = App.objects.create(name = appName, category=c, user_id = u.id, app_logo=File(filename))
        apps.save()

        return HttpResponse("You created %s." % apps.name)
```

Comment: check permission (for apache user) and check disk space

Comment: checked permissions using chmod 777 and the image size is just 25kb so I don't it's an issue.

Comment: could you please show the actual code that saves an image?

Comment: added it in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That message from mod_wsgi with no traceback generally means that the HTTP client closed the connection before all response data could be written back to it by mod_wsgi.

Comment: so what could be the solution?

Comment: There is no solution. It is a normal thing that can happen. You can't prevent users from browsing away from a page before it has been completely returned. Nor can you guard against network issues that cause a broken connection, something that is quite prevalent when the client is running on a mobile device.